# tinymce toggling issue

Tags: tinymce, toggle, wysiwyg, formatter

I'm having the following issue - I currently have a custom toolbar/set of buttons for bold/italic/underline and when each one of them is clicked I'm calling the respective js function. Currently when the bold button is clicked I'm calling

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.toggle('bold');
```

The latter successfully bolds the current selection but, when I press again the bold button, the bold is **NOT** removed. I tried to debug it and the `formatter.remove()` method gets called; then, when I check what's the current selection in its body, the result is correct (there is a selection and it's the one that has been bolded).

If I re-select the text and press the bold button the bold formatting gets removed. I wonder what the issue might be? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: but i got no problem like the one you describe, which  version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: Thanks :) Just noticed that I'm actually using a beta version - 3.5b3 (dull) I shall try with the latest stable instead. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: Got the latest stable version and there's no such issue now :)

Comment: You should add it as an answer so that it no longer stays in 'unanswered' list.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed as of the most recent release.